# lm-sensor doesn't show fan speed

Tags: 22.04, asus, fan, lm-sensors

Well. I'm really tired of this. I'm trying to detect my CPU fan speed but without success. Problem is I have this  Nuvoton 6798D chip (mobo: ASUS TUF GAMING B560M-E) and the only workaround which I found is adding this line to GRUB:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax".

But it's not recommended: https://dannyda.com/2022/01/15/how-to-fix-workaround-sensors-s-tui-commands-does-not-show-fan-speed-from-motherboards-using-nuvoton-nct6798d-asus-asus-rog-asus-prime-asus-tuf-etc/

So I'm curious, is there any other way? Any driver?
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I only know of the `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` solution.

Comment: what does `sensors-detect` output show in the SuperIO section?